# VIM "forgets" last edited line

Tags: normal-mode, default-settings

I've noticed that VIM "forgets" last edited line after some time.
Sometimes when I open a file that I haven't been editing since a few days (maybe 3 and more) and type `'.` in normal mode I'll get the error at the bottom:

> E20: Mark not set

Is it a normal VIM behavior? If not, how can I force it to "remember" the last edited line forever?
Using

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0
```

Comment: Could you tell us what is your `viminfo` setting (`:set viminfo?`)?

Comment: Do you still have the problem?

Comment: The output of it is
`viminfo='100,<50,s10,h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the information is saved in the `.viminfo` file.

The number of files/buffers for which the marks are stored is controlled by the `'` section of the `viminfo` setting.

To set it to a maximum of 500 files/buffers you can use the following command:

```
:set viminfo^='500
```

More information about the `viminfo` setting with: `:help 'viminfo'`.

When the number of files/buffers exceed that limit the information from the old files/buffer is removed from the `.viminfo` file and you get the message you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. I've set it to 500.
If it were 100 before I can imagine that it wasn't enough according to such an algorithm as I edit lots of files. However most of them are forgettable. What I need is probably to force VIM to remember last edited position forever at least of the files in the saved session...
So that they are excluded from this rotation. However I don't know whether VIM supports such a setting.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) If it solve your problem you can accept the answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest ;-)